# Why does the my code output "2467135" instead of "1234567"?

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I have a question about the following code. Why is the output of the code becoming `2467135`? It first gives the output of my own function, then of the `write` function, and finally of the `printf` function. What is the reason for this behavior.

```
int ft_printf(const char *s, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int     i;
    int     len;

    len = 0;
    i = 0;
    va_start(ap, s);
    while (s[i])
    {
        if (s[i] == '%') 
        {
            len += ft_formats(s, ap, ++i);
        }
        else
            len += ft_putchar(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return (len);
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("1");
    ft_printf("2");
    printf("3");
    ft_printf("4");
    printf("5");
    ft_printf("6");
    write(1,"7",1);
}
```

I was expecting `1234567` but the output came out as `2467135`

Comment: printf buffers data till it meets new line symbol `\n`

Answer (score 2):

The output of `ft_printf`, `printf` and `write` does not appear in the source order because of bufferisation: `stdout` is line buffered to a terminal by default, which means the individual digits `1`, `3` and `5` are stored in the output stream buffer until a newline is output or `fflush(stdout)`.  Upon exiting the program, all streams are flushed and closed, hence the `135` appears last in the output.

You can obtain the `123456` output by configuring `stdout` as unbuffered with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` before writing anything to `stdout`.

Comment: Does `putchar` use a different `stdout` buffer or none at all? I mean, the behaviour of the program can only be explained if some of the IO is unbuffered while other IO is not. Otherwise, the result should match the source code.

Comment: @Marco: `putchar` and `printf` use the same buffer, but the OP uses `ft_printf`, which in turn uses `ft_putchar` to output `2`, `4` and `6`.  `ft_putchar` is a local reimplementation  of `putchar` using low level system calls such as `write`.  The OP is probably a student at a top French computing school such as *42* or *Epitech*.